# Hacked : How to know the date our server called pirate's url the first time?

Tags: apache, logging

Our server have been hacked (injected code). We need to find the first date the pirate's url have been called from our server. Where can we find that ? Is there a way to find this in the log ? We found the pirate url in a piece of code on our payment page.

Thank for your precious help !

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Linux server running apache usually all HTTP logs are written to var/log/httpd/

However, the question is how the URL gets called to find real (if there is any).